# Reflecting counts in a table to a field (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

```
liked_table
-----------
user_id | topic | liked
2       | 3     | 1
3       | 3     | 1
5       | 3     | -1


topics_table
------------
topic_id | likes
3        | count(liked field from liked_table where topic from liked_table is this row's topic_id)
```

Can I write a formula like this in MySQL like we do in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than have a table with calculated values you can create a View and have calculated columns in the view. (Accessing data in the view is for the most part identical to a doing the same with an actual table).

[MySQL View Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)